# How to pass the value through onClick and load a page through href in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to load a page through href and send some data through onClick function.
See this is my code.

```
<a href='doc-menu-2.html' onClick='doc_menu_2(10)'>Item Name</a>

<script>
myApp.onPageInit('doc-menu-2', function (page) {

    function doc_menu_2(get_cid)
    {
        alert(get_cid);
    }

})
</script>
```

When I click "Item Name" link, I want to load href page and should pass the doc_menu_2 data to inside function and alert should give value like 10;

I tried to find a solution for this here, but I failed.

Thanks!

Comment: You would need to include the data in the request to the next page. As it's a GET request in this case, you would need to use the querystring

Comment: Can you please explain more. how do I get GET values in js?

Answer (score 0):

I modified the above code. Try it:

```
<a href='doc-menu-2.html' onClick='return doc_menu_2(this, 10)'>Item Name</a>

<script>
function doc_menu_2(obj, get_cid)
{
    var href = obj.href;
    console.log(href, get_cid);
    alert(get_cid);
    window.location = obj.href+'?id='+get_cid
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was working on it today, and just wanted to post my work around.

```
<a href='doc-menu-2.html?parameter_you_need=10'>
```

End if You want to send to some Tab in page

```
<a href='doc-menu-2.html?parameter_you_need=10#tab2'>
```